# Add a row to a sql database which has a identity primary key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a simple test db which has a column called ID which is a Primary Key with autoidentity set.

I am trying to add a new row to the datatable I created using the sqladapter

when i leave the ID column of the new row empty thinking the sql would add it it displays the following error:

```
"Column "ID" doesn't not allow nulls
```

I solved it but giving the ID any value like `dr["ID"] = 99999`

And it worked, but now while the SQL database ignores the value and just gives it the correct number the datatable has the 99999 ID which makes it kinda confusing and will probably throw errors if i try to insert another record

How can i solve this problem?

sorry about that:

```
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "fds";//E.Name;
            dr["Age"] = 12;// E.Age;
            dr["DateOfBirth"] = "1-1-1999";// E.DoB;
            //dr["ID"] = 99999;
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, dt.Rows.Count - 1);
            DBOperations.UpdateTable(dt);
            MessageBox.Show("Record added successfully");

    static internal void UpdateTable(DataTable dt)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        Adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from Emp",con); 
        Adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(Adapter).GetUpdateCommand();
        Adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(Adapter).GetInsertCommand();
        Adapter.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(Adapter).GetDeleteCommand();
        Adapter.Update(dt);
    }
```

DB Script:

```
USE [HR]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Emp]    Script Date: 2/12/2013 8:10:49 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Emp](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Age] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Emp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please show your code. How can we tell what you did wrong if we can't see it?

Comment: Where is the code that creates/returns the InsertCommand?

Comment: Are you sure that ID column is an identity column?  If you try to insert an identity column  you should get an `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Emp' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.` error

Comment: @Tim
the insertCommand is automatically generated using the

Adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(Adapter).GetInsertCommand();

Comment: Please check the table in the database [HR] to see if it has the row(ID=9999) that you inserted.  shf301 is correct, trying to write to the ID column should have generated an error.  Unless you have IDENTITY_INSERT on, which is very unlikely to happen by accident.

Comment: Yeah, what they all said, you must have IDENTITY_INSERT turned on.

Comment: that the automatically generated insert statement:
"INSERT INTO [Emp] ([Name], [Age], [DateOfBirth]) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)"

Comment: @RBarryYoung
The row gets inserted with the correct ID=5 in my case, it ignores whatever i write in c#

Comment: Then I have to assume that whatever `.GetInsertCommand` returns is pretty odd, and/or your original error ("ID does not allow nulls") is being spuriosly generated by your SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: it doesn't even include an ID in the Insert statement as mentioned above :(

"INSERT INTO [Emp] ([Name], [Age], [DateOfBirth]) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)"

Comment: Is the client-side autogenerated insert-command generating a SQL insert statement or is it binding values to a server-side stored procedure? I suspect this error is being raised by the disconnected recordset, not by the database. The PK column has to be defined as identity client-side as well.

Comment: it is a sql insert statement.
In that case where can i set the PK as identity on client side?

Answer (score 3):

Three things you might want to check:

1) You could try

```
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

instead of

```
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, dt.Rows.Count - 1);
```

2) Does the SQL Server create a new ID / complete the statement w/o errors if you run an INSERT statement against the table?  Like

```
INSERT INTO tb_mytable (Name, Age) VALUES ('fds', 12)
```

If not there might be something wrong with the ID field.

3) Have you checked the Adapter's (created) Insert Command for correctness?

Edit: You could also - instead of using the CommandBuilder, try creating the Insert Command manually, like this and see what happens - if this is working ok then there is something wrong with your CommandBuilder:

```
string sql  = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[emp] ";
sql += "(Name, Age, DateOfBirth) ";
sql += "Values (@Name, @Age, @DateOfBirth)";

SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand();
insertCommand.CommandText = sql;

SqlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter();
paramName.ParameterName = "@Name";
paramName.DbType = DbType.AnsiString;
paramName.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
paramName.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
paramName.SourceColumn = "Name";

SqlParameter paramAge = new SqlParameter();
paramAge.ParameterName = "@Age";
paramAge.DbType = DbType.Int32;
paramAge.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
paramAge.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
paramAge.SourceColumn = "Age";

SqlParameter paramDoB = new SqlParameter();
paramDoB.ParameterName = "@DateOfBirth";
paramDoB.DbType = DbType.Date;
paramDoB.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date;
paramDoB.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
paramDoB.SourceColumn = "DateOfBirth";

insertCommand.Parameters.Add(paramName);
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(paramAge);
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(paramDoB);

Adapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from the DataAdapter, I'm pretty sure, not from the database. See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971502.aspx