# Adding to Access DB with INSERT INTO?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have an Access DB with a table (DV1) that have [ID TIME CODE REASON] columns. I'm just trying to update the table. I keep getting a INSERT INTO sytax error. Everything I see looks fine. I've tried everything.
I am opening the database, then I get the error. Any thoughts?

```
private void WRTODB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection machStopDB = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+@"C:\Users\sgarner\Google Drive\Visual Studio 2012\Timer test\WRITE TO DB\WRITE TO DB\Machine_Stop.accdb");
        machStopDB.Open();
        string str = "INSERT INTO DV1(TIME,CODE,REASON)" +
            "VALUES( ('" + DateTime.Now + "'),('" + textBox1.Text + "'),('" + textBox2.Text + "'))";
        OleDbCommand insertCmd = new OleDbCommand(str, machStopDB);
        insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        machStopDB.Close();
    }
```

This is just a test program I am working with.

Comment: Try using parameters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx to make your code more readable

Comment: @Yahya and perhaps more importantly, less vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: I might be wrong, but why you have Parenthesis around each value? single quote should be enough I think.

Comment: @Yahya Not to mention safer.

Comment: `"VALUES(Now(), " + ` Access will supply Now for you.

Answer (score 1):

The following code incorporates the sound ideas offered by the comments above:

```
private void WRTODB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection()) 
        {
            string Source = @"C:\Users\sgarner\Google Drive\Visual Studio 2012\Timer test\WRITE TO DB\WRITE TO DB\Machine_Stop.accdb";
            dbConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Source;
            dbConnection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DV1([TIME],CODE,REASON) VALUES ([pTime],[pCode],[pReason])", dbConnection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pTime", DateTime.Now);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pCode", textBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pReason", textBox2.Text);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Time is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266), you will need to escape it. Why insert ptime when MS Access has Now()?

Comment: Thanks @Remou - I overlooked TIME - will edit post. I  am not clear what you mean by MS-Access has Now()? Do you mean that the Field definition should include a default that specifies Now()? - I would agree with that.

Comment: +1 Yes, but not just that, which would indeed be good, you can simply use now in the sql string `VALUES (Now(),[pCode],` It saves quite a bit of pain.

Comment: About parameters and SqlCommand/OleDbCommand: You might want to take a look here; covers creating parameters manually in depth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838368/add-a-row-to-a-sql-database-which-has-a-identity-primary-key/14839164#14839164; might save a lot of pain especially with datetime and float/double.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting this error message, but I modified the connection string in the answer and perhaps that will correct it.